# Angular 6 can't find .angular-cli.json and change the outDir

Tags: angular, config

I have followed an online tutorial which says that I have to set the outDir inside the .angular-cli.json file. This will put the compiled code in the right directory specified in my app.js folder when I run ng build. The problem is I can't find the file anywhere. Tutorial [link](https://www.sitepoint.com/mean-stack-angular-2-angular-cli/)

The solution is done and has no errors, all I have to do now is connect Angular with the back end I have and run it on localhost:3000. Thus far, I found outdir only in tsconfig.json file. When I run the compiler the files end up in the default dist folder.

Comment: In angular 6, its "angular.json" and output path is "outputPath" under `options` entry

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Tutorial you are referring to is using Angular 2 and the latest version of Angular is 6

CLI projects in angular 6 onwards will be using  `angular.json` instead of `.angular-cli.json` for build and project configuration.

Each CLI workspace has projects, each project has targets, and each target can have configurations.**[Docs](https://blog.angular.io/version-6-of-angular-now-available-cc56b0efa7a4)**
If you want the generated artifacts to be stored in the custom location Modify the output path from `"outputPath": "dist/ng6",` to `"outputPath": "dist/yourcustomlocation",` under `build` target

```
    {
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "ng6": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/ng6",**<----/modify this**
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets":
```

FurtherMore the Tutorial uses `HttpModule` which is deprecated you should use **[HttpClientModule](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6)** instead